# How to create a random number following a lognormal distribution in excel?

Tags: excel, math, random, vba

To create a set of data with a mean of 10 and a standard deviation of 5, as an example, it can be calculated with a normal distribution using this formula:

```
NORMINV(RAND(), Mean, Stdev)
NORMINV(RAND(), 10, 5)
```

This results in numbers ranging from roughly -5 to  to 25 with a frequency distribution that looks normal with most values centerred around the mean.

How to get a similar set of numbers but have them follow a lognormal distribution, one where there is a higher probability of larger numbers and no probability of going below zero?

How to do this using Excel without add-ons?

Tried:

```
 LOGINV(RAND(), Mean, Stdev)
 LOGINV(RAND(), 10, 5)
```

.. but this creates very large numbers (to the power of 20, etc) that look meaningless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lognormal is e^N(m,s).  So the answer, using your construct for normal, would be

```
=EXP( NORMINV(RAND(),Mean,Stdev) )
```

However that will give you very large values.  Next step is to scale the mean and standard deviation.  In pseudocode,

```
scaled mean = ln( m^2 / sqrt( m^2 + s^2 ))
scaled sd = sqrt( ln(( m^2 + s^2 ) / m^2 ))
```

Comment: I am trying to run a monte carlo simulation that pulls a number from an excel generated lognormal distribution. I understand the first equation but am wondering why you scale the mean and standard dev. Thank you.

Comment: I answered my question. This post from the SAS blog explains it. http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/06/04/simulate-lognormal-data-with-specified-mean-and-variance.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying to follow the directions above. Please let me know if I've made any mistakes.

```
Public Function LognormalRV(ByVal SampleMean As Double, ByVal SampleStDev As Double)
    'returns a random variable based on a lognormal distribution
    Dim ScaledMean As Double
    Dim ScaledStDev As Double
    ScaledMean = Log(SampleMean ^ 2 / Sqr(SampleMean ^ 2 + SampleStDev ^ 2))
    ScaledStDev = Sqr(Log((SampleMean ^ 2 + SampleStDev ^ 2) / SampleMean ^ 2))
    LognormalRV = WorksheetFunction.LogNorm_Inv(Rnd(), ScaledMean, ScaledStDev)
End Function
```